# Calculating a union of 2 relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I have 2 relations:
$$ xSy \Leftrightarrow y = 2x$$
and
$$ xTy \Leftrightarrow y = 3x$$
The problem I have is calculating $$x(T \cup S)y$$ and $$xS^+y $$

Could you please help me?

Comment: What is $S^+$? Do you know that binary relations are sets of ordered pairs? Do you understand that given a relation $R$, $xRy$ is short for $(x,y)\in R$?

Comment: $S^+ = \bigcup_{k=1}^{\inf}R^k$ - it was defined as a transitive envelope during the lecture, don't know if the translation is correct.

Comment: @GitGud $R^+$ is the transitive closure of $R$. $xR^+y$ holds if and only if there are $z_1,\dots,z_n$ such that $xRz_1, z_1Rz_2, \dots, z_nRy$ all hold.

Comment: I do understand, but I still don't know how to calculate it

Comment: @Mark : what set are you working in?

Comment: It is defined in $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: This should not be difficult.  Write out some representative elements of $S$ and $T$.  For example, $(5, 10) \in S$.  So is $(3, 6)$.  And $(2, 6) \in T$, as is $(11, 33)$.  Now think about the union of those two sets:  they consist of all ordered pairs of natural numbers for which the second coordinate is either a multiple of $2$ or $3$ of the first coordinate.

Answer (score 2):

Start with an arbitrary $$x\in \mathbb{N}$$ then $$(x,2x)\in S, (x,4x)\in S^2, (x,8x)\in S^3, \ldots, (x,2^nx)\in S^n, \ldots$$ so we can say

$$ xS^+y \Leftrightarrow \exists n\in \mathbb{N} s.t. y=2^nx $$